# Can't mount samba share

Tags: mount, samba

I'm trying to mount a samba host located at 192.168.2.5. I can ping the host, I can open the share on Ubuntu and windows (with the credentials). When I try to manually connect:

```
pi@raspberrypi-web-server ~ $ smbclient -L 192.168.2.5
Enter pi's password:
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.6.6]

Sharename       Type      Comment
---------       ----      -------
IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (raspberrypi-media server)
Media Folder    Disk      Media Folder
print$          Disk      Printer Drivers
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.6.6]

Server               Comment
---------            -------
RASPBERRYPI-MEDI     raspberrypi-media server

Workgroup            Master
---------            -------
WORKGROUP
```

I have this line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
//192.168.2.5/ /mnt/smb cifs user=maikel,pass=PASSWORD,_netdev 0 0
```

But whenever I do:

```
sudo mount -a
```

I get the following error:

```
Retrying with upper case share name mount error(6): No such device or
address Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Why doesn't my mount work? I've tried `host raspberrypi-media` but I got the same error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ mount -t cifs -o user=maikel,pass=PASSWORD,_netdev \
    '//192.168.2.5/Media Folder' /mnt/smb
```

This should work.  Also, try this to make sure you have permissions:

```
$ smbclient '\\192.168.2.5\Media Folder' -U maikel
```

Type in your password and type in `ls` at the `smbclient` prompt.

Comment: The single quotes did the job. i used an \040 (space) in /etc/fstab and it works! Wow thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the trailing / on "//192.168.2.5/" was the original problem, by the way: share names do not end with a / and you had no share name in there.

You needed this:

```
//192.168.2.5 /mnt/smb cifs user=maikel,pass=PASSWORD,_netdev 0 0
```